# Insert Row Conditional Format

Tags: excel, excel-2007, excel-formula, excel-2010, vba

I was wondering, is it possible to insert a new row in excel with conditional formatting? I know it is possible with VBA and macros but is it possible with formatting? i tried looking at every function and format there is in excel and i didn't seem to find any.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not possible to insert a row using conditional formatting...........as you point out, this would require a macro.